# How can I upload Storage images from Firebase database onto my menu page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I want to state that I am fairly new to reactjs and firebase. I am trying to upload images I have in my firebase storage and have it appear on my menu page for my website. So far I can read and upload data from my database, but I don't quite understand how to upload images. Any help?

```
import './Home.css';

import React from "react";
import Categories from "./Categories";
import items from "./data";
import { menu_Chow_Mein } from './firebase/firebaseConfig';
import { useState, useEffect, ReactDOM} from 'react';
import {collection, doc, setDoc, addDoc, getDocs} from 'firebase/firestore';



function Menu() {

  const [food, setFood] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getFood = async () => {
        const data = await getDocs(menu_Chow_Mein);
        setFood(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id})));

    };
    getFood();
  }, []);
  
  return(
      <div className='menu'>
        <div className="top-section"></div>
        {food.map((item) => {
          return (
            <article key={item.id} className="menu-items">
              <img src={item.ImageURL} alt={item.Name} className="photo" />
              <div className="item-info">
                <header>
                  <h4>{item.Name}</h4>
                  <h4 className="price">${item.Price}</h4>
                </header>
              
                <p className="item-text">{item.Description}</p>
              </div>
            </article>
          );
        })}
        </div>
    );
  }
  
  export default Menu;
```

Also, I attached some photos from my firebase database and storage.

[image: URL]
[image: Firebase Database Error]

Answer (score 1):

Generally you would store the image URL from Firebase storage in the Firestore document along with name and price fields. Then while mapping all the items to your UI, you can set the src of image:

```
<p className="item-text">{item.Description}</p>
<img src={item.imageURL} />
```

Comment: @saulcinho can you explain where are you trying to upload images from?

Comment: So, on my Cloud Firestore, I added a new field(reference) and named it "ImageURL" then I added the location of specific food images from Storage. I edited this post to show up to date images on how my database and storage looks like.

Comment: @saulcinho so the issue image is not being displayed right? Can you please share an updated screenshot of your Firestore document where you've added image URL field? You can edit and add that in your question.

Comment: Do you see them? I updated my code as well, but it wasn't too much change. I replaced "item.img" to "item.ImageURL" in this line"<img src={item.ImageURL} alt={item.Name} className="photo" />"

Comment: @saulcinho you need the URL starting with `https://` and having a `?token=` at the end. If you click that hyperlink in Firebase storage console, it'll redirect you to that link. Can you try pasting that link in Firestore document and then try? Not the "storage location"

Comment: I updated this post. I cannot directly type in a URL, I tried it. Any help?

Comment: @saulcinho please change the type to **string** and not reference. The reference type refers to a Document Reference.

Comment: LET'S GO! YOU'RE AWESOME! THANKY YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Hey @Dharmaraj can you help me with my second most recent question? I cannot display all food items from my database.